# CoreData NSValueTransformer cannot be found after adding new Core Data version

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a `note` attribute in Core Data, which is `Transformable`.

[image]

I am using `NSAttributedStringTransformer` as follows:

```
@objc(NSAttributedStringTransformer)
class NSAttributedStringTransformer: NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer {
        override class var allowedTopLevelClasses: [AnyClass] {
                return super.allowedTopLevelClasses + [NSAttributedString.self]
        }
}
```

The code works as expected. When I add new Core Data version. I get the following `no NSValueTransformer with class name 'NSAttributedStringTransformer' was found for attribute 'note' on entity 'NotesEntity'`. I haven't made any other changes. Do I need to change the `NSAttributedStringTransformer` in order to work with Core Data versions?

Comment: Isn't it necessary to register the transformer?

Comment: I am calling register at app init. 
```
extension NSAttributedStringTransformer {
    static let name = NSValueTransformerName(rawValue: String(describing: NSAttributedStringTransformer.self))

    public static func register() {
        let transformer = NSAttributedStringTransformer()
        ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(transformer, forName: name)
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to say that in the question, perhaps.